# Java opts for JBoss, Hudson, Maven

Tags: jboss, maven, jvm, hudson, jenkins

For our project, maven is call by hudson(jenkins) and hudson is deployed by JBoss on a Window server. We just increased the physical RAM for the machine and I would like to know;

1 - Do we have to reconfigure the JAVA_Opts (i.e. -Xmx, -Xms, MaxPermgen, MaxNew...) to fully utilise the extra RAM.

2 - If yes, then when should I place those setting? in JBoss? Mavan? Hudson?

3 - If we assigned conflicting Java_opts to the three of them, which get the highest priority?

4 - How to set Java_opts on JBoss run.sh?

Comment: Are you really running Hudson in JBoss ? Why? Just use Tomcat etc. or the build-in- jetty...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. That's was the decision made before I join the team, but presumably, JBoss is more extendible than other app server and we need that as our project is quite specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes. Java only uses as much ram for the java heap as was configured. if you configured xmx and xms already you will have to reconfigure it. (if you haven't you should do so now; jboss has them configured to a low default).
2. Since hudson is deployed in jboss if you want more ram for your hudson you have to change the jboss settings. Since maven runs in the hudson/jboss jvm (afaik) its again the jboss start script.
3. It should be pointless to assign java opts to a script that never starts a jvm.
4. the environment variable is JAVA_OPTS. set it. There also the run.conf file and there are examples for start scripts in the jboss/bin folder. They are conveniently named jboss_init_

Comment: Thanks, where should I add -Xmx in the run.sh for JBoss? setting the Java_opts in environment variable is not a feasible solution because it will get pass on to other JVM that run on the build server

Comment: than use one of the jboss start scripts (if you are runing debian its jboss_init_redhead. In this script is a bash variable named JAVA_OPS that you can set.